# Analysis Proof of Inflection Points

Tags: calculus, analysis

[image]

We are supposed to prove this, and it seems relatively simple, but as per usual, I don't know where to start. I assume that a big factor is that the third derivative is not zero at $x_0$, which means that it is either concave up or down, while the second derivative being zero means the slope of $f$ is zero at $x_0$. But I don't know how to do a proof, not a calc 1 explanation... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are given that $f'''$ is continuous. Since $f'''(x_0) \not= 0$ there exists a neighborhood $I$ of $x_0$ on which $f'''$ is either always positive or always negative. In (say) the former case, $f''' > 0$ so that $f''$ is increasing on $I$, and thus $f'' < 0$ on an interval $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0)$ and $f'' > 0$ on an interval $(x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$. Thus the concavity of $f$ switches at $x_0$, meaning that the graph inflects there.

Comment: great, Thanks for your help!